# Extract 'deviance' simultaneously from multiple objects

Tags: r

I'm R beginner

From a certain data set, 
I've fitted different 10 log-linear models, according to multiple
combination of explain variables.

Model1
Model2
Model3
  .
  .
  .
Model10

I want extract deviance of each model, from model1 to model10

I can extract like below
deviance(model1)
deviance(model2)
      .
      .
      .
deviance(model10)

but i think it takes time, and no good-looking.

How can I extract deviance 'simultaneously' from multiple object?

is there any function or package?

Comment: Save your models in a list and call `lapply(modellist, deviance)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach maybe

```
lapply(mget(paste0("model",1:10)),deviance)
```